Sprinboot api application performance test
I want to test the performance of my backend REST API application written with Spring Boot under high requests.
How can I perform this process?
Which tools should I use and what should I do step by step?
What are the best practices for performance tests and how should I analyse the results?

this question is not full. Where are the details of your API? Is it REST or something else? For performance, you could play and write logic in Java. However, it is quite tricky to make the load stable per second. Or use specific tools like JMeter or Gatling.

My API is a RestAPI. @catch23

For testing REST API I will suggest starting with JMeter.
It will be the fastest way of checking performance.
Useful sources:

JMeter Tutorial: Getting Started With the Basics
REST API Testing using Apache JMeter (step by step guide)
Official documentation

